# `make` command not found Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have the JenkinsFile as followed

```
pipeline {
agent any
environment {
    DISABLE_AUTH = 'true'
    DB_ENGINE    = 'sqlite'
}
stages {
    stage('Run unit/integration tests') {
        steps {
            sh 'make test'
        }
    }
    stage('Build application artefacts') {
        steps {
            sh 'make build'
        }
    }
    stage('Create release environment and run acceptance tests') {
        steps {
            sh 'make release'
        }
    }
    stage('Example') {
        steps {
            echo 'Reached example'
        }
    }


}
```

and Makefile as follows

```
test:
${INFO} "Pulling latest images..."
@ docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) pull
${INFO} "Building images..."
@ docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) build --pull test
@ docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) build cache
${INFO} "Ensuring database is ready..."
@ docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) up agent
${INFO} "Running tests..."
@ docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) up test
# @ cd $$(docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) ps -q test):/reports
# @ cp *.xml ./reports
@ echo $$(docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) ps -q test)
@ docker cp $$(docker-compose -p $(DEV_PROJECT) -f $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) ps -q test):**/reports/*.xml
${CHECK} $(DEV_PROJECT) $(DEV_COMPOSE_FILE) test
${INFO} "Testing complete"
```

And when i run it on Jenkins it gives the error that 'make command not found' on the console of the Jenkins.I think this is because of the environment variable.How to fix this?

Comment: to debug the issue, i suggest to login to the executor as jenkins user (via ssh), and run those commands from the shell

Comment: Do you have `make` on the node which runs the pipeline?